# Version of Windows Imaging Component

Tags: azure, tiff, imaging, wic, libtiff.net

How can I check what version of Windows Imaging Component is installed on a Windows machine? I suspect the Windows 2008 Servers used in Azure do not have the same version that I have on my Windows 7 development machine. I just want to verify that as I need the latest TIFF codec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will not make a definite statement, but I think that the WIC on the Windows Azure is the same what you have on your Windows 7. Just be aware that there are [2 OS families in Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee924680.aspx). OS Family 1.x is using Windows Server 2008 SP1 as base, while OS Family 2 is using Windows Server 2008 R2 as base.

From what I read about WIC, I see it is part of Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2, so, if you target your application for OS Family 2, you shall nothave issues. Unless there is some update, or more recent version which has installer. If there is an installer, you can simply use a startup task to install the exact version you need.

**UPDATE**

Refering [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/windowswic/thread/ab2d227b-c752-4c8b-b1ac-77d17d4bfc05) confirms that Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2 come with WIC. While [a platform update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971644) is required for Windows Vist / Windows Server 2008 (you must install Server 2008 SP2 before the update is available). So, if you target OS Family 2.x (recommended anyway) you get the same WIC you get in your Windows 7 machine.