# Setting BitmapMetadata.Title in service running on Windows Server 2003 Web Edition throws NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, wcf, bitmap, metadata, windows-server-2003

So I have this method to set some basic MetaData tags which eventually will be added to my image:

```
        BitmapMetadata metaData = new BitmapMetadata("jpg");
        foreach (var t in tags)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (t.Key)
                {
                    case "Author":
                        metaData.Author = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string>(new string[] { t.Value });
                        break;

                    case "Rating":
                        int rating = 0;
                        if (int.TryParse(t.Value, out rating))
                        {
                            metaData.Rating = rating;
                        }
                        break;

                    case "Subject":
                        metaData.Subject = t.Value;
                        break;

                    case "Title":
                        metaData.Title = t.Value;
                        break;

                    case "Comment":
                        metaData.Comment = t.Value;
                        break;

                    default:
                        keywords.Add(string.Format("{0}:{1}", t.Key, t.Value));
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Do some logging
            }
        }
```

And I keep getting the error:

> System.NotSupportedException: No imaging component suitable to
>   complete this operation was found. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x88982F50 \   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- \   at
>   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapMetadata.SetQuery(String query,
>   Object value) \   at
>   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapMetadata.set_Title(String value)

Running as localhost on Windows 8.1 this works fine. As soon as I deploy my service to my Windows Server 2003 Web Edition it throws the shown error. What is happening?

Comment: Maybe you're missing a JPEG encoder. This is normally in System.Drawing.dll, in namespace System.Drawing.Imaging. Try doing "ImageCodecInfo[] encoderArray = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();" and check that there is at least one result in the returned array.

Comment: I have ran that method and printed the Codec name and got:
Built-in BMP Codec,
Built-in GIF Codec,
Built-in TIFF Codec, 
Built-in PNG Codec,

I'm guessing I'm missing a jpg encoder? How do I go about installing a jpg encoder on my Windows 2003 server?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I have no knowledge about this specific situation. You could maybe try installing this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958911 (But if it causes problems, please don't blame me. :-)

Comment: You can also run that statement on your Windows 8.1 system to see what the expected result should be.

Comment: Yes on windows 8.1 I ran the same statement and got a Built in JPG encoder. I will probably try installing [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=32) and update my answer to how it goes

Comment: So turns out I did have a JPG encoder and that install went through ok but didnt fix my issue sadly

Comment: Sorry I sent you on a wild goose chase. But I still suspect it has something to do with a missing or not-good-enough JPEG encoder/decoder. Maybe your JPEG codec isn't good enough for the version of .Net you're using? There's this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811229/wic-createdecoderfromstream-returning-0x88982f50-post-server-migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix to this was to explicitly use the SetQuery for the metadata...
For Example:

```
BitmapMetadata jpgData = new BitmapMetadata("jpg");
jpgData.SetQuery("/app13/irb/8bimiptc/iptc/object name", "Test Title");
jpgData.SetQuery("/app13/irb/8bimiptc/iptc/keywords", "Test Tag");
jpgData.SetQuery("/app13/irb/8bimiptc/iptc/date created", "20090512");
jpgData.SetQuery("/app13/irb/8bimiptc/iptc/time created", "115300-0800");
jpgData.SetQuery("/app13/irb/8bimiptc/iptc/caption", "Test Comment");
jpgData.SetQuery("/app13/irb/8bimiptc/iptc/by-line", "Test Author");
jpgData.SetQuery("/app13/irb/8bimiptc/iptc/copyright notice", "Copyright 2009");
```

From a comment on [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata(v=vs.90))

This is because the WIC used in windows server 2003 is not the same as a Windows 7/8 one and cannot be updated. and so metadata.Title etc. throw notfoundexception