# WICConvertBitmapSource() throws error for GUID_WICPixelFormat16bppCbCr

Tags: c++, image, wic

I need to convert rgb to YCBCR pixel format. and i used `WICConvertBitmapSource()`. my source pixel format is `GUID_WICPixelFormat24bppBGR`. And iwanted to convert it to `GUID_WICPixelFormat16bppCbCr`

when I trying to pass that to the function, its return HRESULT as 0x88982F50.
if i pass `GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGRA` ,the functions returns no error

my questions are

1. why is my conversion fail
2. how should i convert RGB to YCbCr
   correctly
3. and what does 0x88982F50 means actually

This is how i tried.

```
int mwic_bitmap_converter 
(
REFWICPixelFormatGUID dstPixelFormt,    /* [in] Pixel format to be converted */
IWICBitmapSource* piBitmapSource,       /* [in] Image Data */
IWICBitmapSource** ppiBitmapDst         /* [out]converted image data */
)
{
    WICPixelFormatGUID srcPixelFormat = { 0 };  /* Pixel format of the source */
    UINT iWidth = 0, iHeight = 0;               /* Size of the source */
    UINT cbStride;                              /* Stride of the bitmap */
    UINT cbBufferSize;                          /* Size of the buffer */
    float* pixels;                              /* Pixel buffer */

    piBitmapSource->GetSize(&iWidth,&iHeight);
    piBitmapSource->GetPixelFormat(&srcPixelFormat);

    if (!IsEqualGUID(srcPixelFormat, dstPixelFormt))
    {
        //this line gives the error
        hr = WICConvertBitmapSource(dstPixelFormt, piBitmapSource, ppiBitmapDst);
    }
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811229/wic-createdecoderfromstream-returning-0x88982f50-post-server-migration

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thankyou. but i couldnt find an answer in there :/

Comment: Visual Studio's build in Error Lookjup tool  (under Tools > Error Lookup) should tell you: 0x88982F50 is "The component cannot be found."

Comment: [Windows 8.1 required](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).